# Push Notification/Service Worker Issue

Tags: service, notifications, push, worker

I'm trying to send push notifications to users. All seems to be doing well when clicking on notifications right when it arrives. VIsitor gets redirected to correct URL, but problems start when I wait about 20 minutes. Then visitor gets redirected to UNDEFINED URL. Meaning push notification no longer remembers the URL.

Here is my service worker:

```
'use strict';

self.addEventListener('push', function(event) {
  console.log('[Service Worker] Push Received.');
  console.log(`[Service Worker] Push had this data: `);
  console.log(JSON.parse(event.data.text()));//
  const notificationObject = JSON.parse(event.data.text());//

  const title = notificationObject.title;//modified from tutorial to make it more dynamic
  const options = {
    body: notificationObject.msg,
    icon: notificationObject.icon,
    badge: notificationObject.badge,
  };
  self.notificationURL = notificationObject.data;
  event.waitUntil(self.registration.showNotification(title, options));
});

self.addEventListener('notificationclick', function(event) {
  console.log('[Service Worker] Notification click Received.');
  //console.log(self.notificationURL);
  event.notification.close();

  event.waitUntil(
    clients.openWindow(self.notificationURL)
  );
});
```

Anyone have any idea why user get redirects to UNDEFINED page after 20 minutes, but all is well for the first 20 minutes?

Can the push service somehow forget the sent data? This is happening on both desktop & android.

Comment: I"m seeing this same behavior.  Did you ever figure this out?

Comment: Yes. This is just what happens. I found a way around it by saving the URL in cache and then retrieving from cache when somebody click on push.

Comment: I found a better way yesterday actually.  You need to create a new "data" model in the notification object that contains the url property, then you can retrieve that in the notficationclick event through event.notification.data object.